# Extract Email address from a table in .HTMLbody

Tags: regex, vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I would like to reply to a webform extracting the email address from the form.

The webform is in a table, thus the ParseTextLinePair() function returns blanks as the email address in the column next to the label.

How can I extract the email address from a webform?

```
Sub ReplywithTemplatev2()
Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oRespond As Outlook.MailItem

'Get Email
    Dim intLocAddress As Integer
    Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
    Dim strAddress As String

Set Item = GetCurrentItem()

If Item.Class = olMail Then

        ' find the requestor address
        strAddress = ParseTextLinePair(Item.Body, "Email-Adresse des Ansprechpartners *")


' This sends a response back using a template
Set oRespond = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Reply.oft")

With oRespond
    .Recipients.Add Item.SenderEmailAddress
    .Subject = "Your Subject Goes Here"
    .HTMLBody = oRespond.HTMLBody & vbCrLf & _
              "---- original message below ---" & vbCrLf & _
               Item.HTMLBody & vbCrLf

' includes the original message as an attachment
   ' .Attachments.Add Item

   oRespond.To = strAddress

' use this for testing, change to .send once you have it working as desired
    .Display


End With

End If
Set oRespond = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

```
Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

---

```
Function ParseTextLinePair(strSource As String, strLabel As String)
    Dim intLocLabel As Integer
    Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
    Dim intLenLabel As Integer
    Dim strText As String

    ' locate the label in the source text
    intLocLabel = InStr(strSource, strLabel)
    intLenLabel = Len(strLabel)
        If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, strSource, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            strText = Mid(strSource, _
                            intLocLabel, _
                            intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
            intLocLabel = Mid(strSource, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If
    ParseTextLinePair = Trim(strText)
End Function
```

A picture of the table to clarify.

[image]

Comment: You may have better luck with `Item.HTMLBody` as that returns a structured HTML string which you could use to parse out the appropriate `<TD>` elements from the `<Table>`. Don't use string functions to parse HTML, though, there are libraries specifically designed for that which would be better suited. Otherwise, there may be a simpler approach if you can screenshot what this email Table looks like?

Comment: Added Screenshot. Table with 2 Columns and 9 Rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked in to Regular Expressions in VBA, I haven't worked on it in while but here is an example.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub Example()
    Dim Item As MailItem
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Dim Search_Email As String
    Dim Pattern As String     
    Dim Matches As Variant

    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VbScript.RegExp")

    Pattern = "\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b"

    For Each Item In ActiveExplorer.Selection

        Search_Email = Item.body

        With RegExp
            .Global = False
            .Pattern = Pattern
            .IgnoreCase = True
            Set Matches = .Execute(Search_Email)
        End With

        If Matches.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print Matches(0)
        Else
            Debug.Print "Not Found "
        End If

    Next

    Set RegExp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Or ***`Pattern = "(\S*@\w+\.\w+)"`*** Or ***`"(\w+(?:\W+\w+)*@\w+\.\w+)"`***

---

[*Regular-expressions.info/tutorial*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

**`\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b`** Simple pattern that describes an email address.

*A series of letters, digits, dots, underscores, percentage signs and hyphens, followed by an at sign, followed by another series of letters, digits and hyphens, finally followed by a single dot and two or more letters*

**`[A-Z0-9._%+-]+`** *Match a single character present in the list below*

**`A-Z`** *A single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)*

**`0-9`** *A single character in the range between 0 and 9*

**`._%+-`** *A single character in the list*

**`@`** *Matches the character @ literally*

---

Quantifiers

*[Udemy.com/vba-regex/](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-regex/)*

```
+---------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Pattern |                   Meaning                   |                          Example                           |
+---------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|         |                                             |                                                            |
| –       | Stands for  a range                         | a-z means all the letters a to z                           |
| []      | Stands for any one of the characters quoted | [abc] means either a, b or c.[A-Z] means either A, B, …, Z |
| ()      | Used for grouping purposes                  |                                                            |
| |       | Meaning is ‘or’                             | X|Y, means X or Y                                          |
| +       | Matches the character one or more times     | zo+ matches ‘zoo’, but not ‘z’                             |
| *       | Matches the character zero or more times    | “lo*” matches either “l” or “loo”                          |
| ?       | Matches the character zero or once          | “b?ve?” matches the “ve” in “never”.                       |
+---------+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[*Wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Regular_Expressions*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic/Regular_Expressions)

[*https://regex101.com/r/oP2yR0/1*](https://regex101.com/r/oP2yR0/1)

Comment: awesome thanks that works for the email address.

the reason way i wanted to use a table based solution or the solution above is that i would also like to retrieve the entry from the first row in the second column.

Comment: Appears the question about extracting an email address was answered satisfactorily. Consider accepting it and creating a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: How about when there is more than 1 email address?