# Quickly handle error sending email to address which does not exist

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am using the library - Microsoft Outlook in Excel.

For example:
I have got 100 records when in each record is other mail address.
But in some records, there are 2-5 email addresses.

When I am using the function called

```
.Send
```

It is sending the emails in 'background'. But when the VBA will meet error it is stopped.

Example source issues:

- lack of dot in email address
- email addresses are not separated (example: email@gmail.comemail2@gmail.com
- wrong email address (emailgmailcom)

The issue occurs when Outlook wants to send email on address which does not exist.

Is any chance to check if the email addresses are good but not to write 30-50 lines of code?

Comment: Use Regular expressions - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39588282/4539709

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I just wondering what if I will have tons of these issues. Anyway I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `On Error Resume Next` after each `.Send` I would mark that record as send. When macro is done I could check your list for unsend markers, to check for errors.

Checking if emial is correct, you will never know how long should email adress be so checking length is not an option.

Is it posible that those records are know to you? Maybe some kinde of list, that you could comper those with?

Comment: I will try this what did you wrote. Then if the email is correct I will send it and when will be issue I will write in other column 'wrong email'. Then at the end after all of records I will delete these where is not information about error and I will get all email when the issue occurs. 

Thanks! +1

Comment: Nie ma za co ;)