# How to parse a subject line to generate then launch a URL?

Tags: vba, outlook

We have an an internal web site that builds MSI packages via JIRA Requests. The website accepts GET variables via the url.

For every email that comes in with a subject such as:
`JIRA: (V-1244) TEST: Automatic Tool Builder`

I'd like to scrape the numbers after "V-" into this link:
`https://test.tool/gen.php?v=1244&submitV=Submit`

After the link is generated I want to launch the url in a browser.

As a novice with VBA I am looking for a direction to begin. I have searched but haven't found something quite as what's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mucking around a bit I finally figured it out! What this code does is setup a listener at application startup then any email that comes in it checks anywhere in the  subject for "JIRA" since the subject line is always static just the 4 numbers change I break down the subject into an array using `SPLIT()`. I then query the array for the portion of the subject I need and use `MID()` to just extract the ID I need for the URL. Once the URL is complete I join the portions of the URL together into one variable which outputs the complete URL I need to execute. From there I launch and execute the browser using `CreateObject("Shell.Application")` and thats that it works :D! One thing to mention here is that in order for this to work the script has to be placed in `ThisOutlookSession` Under Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Project when you hit ALT + F11 while in outlook and after the script is saved you have to restart outlook for it to load. You also have to go to Trust Center which is located under FILE -> Options -> Trust Center click the Trust Center Settings Button and under that menu select "Macro Settings" and set the option to "Notifications for all macros"
that way it will notify you to enable macros when outlook is launched. The lines of code that are quoted out are 1. the msgbox which i was using to show me the output of my variables and 2. at the very end other items I can query from the email itself. I left those there to possibly help others if they were trying to query other portions of the incoming email.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace

  Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim MessageInfo
Dim Result
Dim vID
Dim vURL1
Dim vURL2
Dim vURL3
Dim fullVID
Dim fullVURL


If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" And InStr(1, Item.Subject, "JIRA") > 0 Then
Dim s As String: s = Item.Subject

fullVID = Split(s, " ")(2)
vID = Mid(fullVID, 7, 4)
vURL1 = "https://test.tool/gen.php?v="
vURL2 = vID
vURL3 = "&submitV=Submit"
fullVURL = vURL1 & vURL2 & vURL3


    MessageInfo = "" & _
        "Subject : " & Item.Subject & vbCrLf & _
        "Variable 1 : " & Split(s, " ")(0) & vbCrLf & _
        "JIRA V : " & vID & vbCrLf & _
        "Create V URL : " & fullVURL

    'Result = MsgBox(MessageInfo, vbOKOnly, "New JIRA Ticket Received")

Dim build
Set build = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
build.ShellExecute "Chrome.exe", fullVURL, "", "", 1

End If

ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitNewItem
End Sub

'"Message Body : " & vbCrLf & Item.Body
'"Sender : " & Item.SenderEmailAddress & vbCrLf & _
'"Sent : " & Item.SentOn & vbCrLf & _
'"Received : " & Item.ReceivedTime & vbCrLf & _
'"Size : " & Item.Size
```

Answer (score 0):

*Work with Regex*

*Example*

> ```
> \((.*)\)
> ```

*https://regex101.com/r/b6VPxR/1*

[image]

*VBA https://stackoverflow.com/a/39588282/4539709*