# Cut the Email address(es) from within body of email text and paste into the to field

Tags: vba, outlook

I am hoping someone can assist me with current project.  I have a text document that I have to import into word.  Each page needs to be sent via email to the recipient(s) listed within the body.

I have been able to successfully copy the page from word and open an Outlook message and paste the text.

The email address(es) will be noted in the body of the text.  Is there possibly a way using vba to cut the addresses and paste them into the To field of the message?

Here is my current code:

```
Sub Paste()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim str_jpeg_file As String
str_jpeg_file = "F:\User\New folder\Logo.jpg"


'Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object
    'Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    'xlSheet.UsedRange.Copy

    'On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("H:\Templates\Statement Customer .msg")
    MyItem.Display
    With MyItem
        .BodyFormat = 2
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Customer Statement "

SendKeys "{right}{down}^({v})", True
End With
End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance!!`

Comment: Try looking at [this site](https://www.devhut.net/vba-extract-email-addresses-from-a-string/) for some help

Comment: I have tried using the code on the link, but I am completely ignorant on using procedures and cannot seem to find information on how to incorporate it.  Can you please help clarify?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract Email address from a table in .HTMLbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563181/extract-email-address-from-a-table-in-htmlbody)

Comment: no, I'm afraid not